# Where should I save a semi-temporary database?

Tags: database, delphi, directory, temporary

I have an application where I would like to save some raw files in a folder structure on the client's computer. This EXE is completely stand-alone, and could possibly be running from a CD, or otherwise from a location which is read-only. Therefore, I cannot save my data in the EXE location. I would like to basically "ask" Windows where I should save the files, or save them in the proper location.

Where should I save this data on a client computer somewhat permanently but yet in a location where applications typically store their data? Since this application doesn't have an installer, I don't know how the permissions to certain program data folders will work out. I need an example of producing a common path for my application. Any instance of the app running on the same machine should know to look in this one dedicated location for this data.

PS - I mean semi-temporary database because the database is expected to stay in tact for a long period of time, but there's a possibility it may be erased to clean up, in which case it would automatically create a new one. The data its self can be considered somewhat of a cache.

EDIT

As far as windows user sessions, this is intended to be a global location for any windows session, and this application is actually a service which will be running in session 0.

Comment: You know, that your application in this use case - without installation - needs to have admin rights?

Comment: I have never seen a service running from CD. How do you make ist start?

Comment: @UweRaabe It compiles as both a service and windows application, it could run either way.

Comment: There is no safe way to get a writeable to all users path location without installation/"first run" with admin rights. CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA mapping path is default just ReadOnly to all users. You have to change security for your application path

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Refer to [MSDN CSIDL listing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762494%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and use the [SHGetFolderPath() function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762181%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Map the CSIDL CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA to a physical directory.

From MSDN:

> The file system directory that contains application data for all
>   users. A typical path is C:\Documents and Settings\All
>   Users\Application Data. This folder is used for application data that
>   is not user specific. For example, an application can store a
>   spell-check dictionary, a database of clip art, or a log file in the
>   CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA folder. This information will not roam and is
>   available to anyone using the computer.

Beneath this directory, create a directory named after the vendor (your company), and beneath that, a directory for your application. Then put your database in there.

**Note:** Don't use CSIDL_COMMON_DOCUMENTS/ FOLDERID_PublicDocuments. This is for document-like files that can be shared across different applications. For proprietary data, like databases, use CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA . Also files in CSIDL_COMMON_DOCUMENTS may be 'roamed' by the operating system - something you **definitely don't want** for a temporary database.

**Note:** For Vista onwards use [SHGetKnownFolderPath()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762188%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but for XP or cross-version, use SHGetFolderPath().

Comment: you will need to initially grant `modify` permissions to `CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA\<your_product>` if you want all users to read-write to it.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are talking about temporary data, the most obvious path would be the windows temp directory:

```
function GetTempDirectory: String;
var
  TempFolder: array[0..MAX_PATH] of Char;
begin
  GetTempPathW(MAX_PATH, @TempFolder);
  Result := TempFolder;
end;
```

Make sure to keep your files open as long as the application is active, so that the user can't delete your files whenever he decides to clean his temp directory.

Comment: That was my first notion, but I intend for the files to stay in place even when restarting the machine.

Comment: But this is only User Temp Folder and only that user can read/write data to it. Any Instance did not limit to only one user ... maybe the question is not clear to this

Comment: @JerryDodge Content of temp folder stay in place when restarting if you did not erase them ... whats the problem

Comment: I have had experiences otherwise, where all the files are deleted as soon as the app closes. But then again, I'm probably mistaken for a self-extractable package. Never really tried to save files directly to a temp folder.

Comment: As far as leaving files open, something not mentioned, different instances are expected to access the same files at the same time, so I can't leave them open necessarily for just one instance. That's however another matter.

Comment: @JerryDodge Creating a File with FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE will automatic delete when FileHandle is closed. Thats maybe what the application did you examined

Comment: No I confirmed, the "WExtract" / "IExpress" tools which come with Windows to create self-extracting packages has this behavior. It extracts to a temp folder and runs the app as specified, and when that app ends, it deletes the temp files.

Comment: That being said, as long as I'm sure these files won't get automatically deleted without the user's say, the Temp folder should be fine for what I need.